# contextmenu event on an overlay covering a YouTube iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Hi I can't seem to figure out why Firefox won't trigger the contextmenu event on a div that covers a YouTube iframe. In Chrome or Safari the event fires but nothing happens in Firefox. I'm using wmode=opaque in the embed URL as the first parameter. I've tried wmode=transparent it doesn't make a difference.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="cover"></div>
    <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/B3YbODo7ieQ?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    outline:1px solid blue;
}
    #container > div.cover {
        position:absolute;
        top:0; left:0;
        z-index:5;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }

    #container > iframe {
        position:absolute;
        top:0; left:0;
        z-index:1;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }
```

JS:

```
$( '#container' ).find( 'div.cover' ).on( 'contextmenu', function( ) {
    console.log( 'rclick' );
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LT8BL/

Any ideas on how to fix?

---

Update: It works on Win7/8 but not Mac? Tried a pure event listener that doesn't fire either.

Comment: contextmenu event is fired for me (FF 27.0.1 Win7)

Comment: That's really odd it doesn't work on my Mac using FF 27.0.1.

Comment: Try set `background-color: #fff; opacity:0.01` .. solved it for me on older browsers long time ago

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately that doesn't work either. You meant those for div.cover I presume?

Comment: Also try move the "cover div" tag in the html after the iframe tag, even if you have set z-index to achieve the same effect, one can't know for sure if it's enough with that .. I also have some vague memory needed to do that for some other reason

Comment: @Jonathan .. yes, I ment the div.cover

Comment: What if you put some content into the div.cover, like a text, and click on that. Still no context menu?

Comment: Tried swapping node placement and adding some garbage text to div.cover and still nothing. Starting to think this might be a bug in the browser...